# How can I install iterm2 bash-it themes?

Tags: bash, terminal, iterm2, bash-it

The instructions aren't too newbie friendly.  At least not for me.

Here is the github repo for bash-it: https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it

I was able to clone the repo and run it.

Immediately once I close then reopen iterm I get the following errors.  How can I resolve these?

[image] 
I tried simply entering:

install argcomplete

sudo install argcomplete

sudo pip install argcomplete

nothing works.

Ultimately I want to install themes, specifically Zork: https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes

The instructions simply say, export the BASH_IT_THEME variable.  It doesn't tell you how.  Then it says to define the following ... in your shell, but not how.

Can anyone help here?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a variable is simply done through

```
export variable
```

Exporting a Variable means it won't be just active in your currently opened shell but will also be available in programs that are being ran from that shell.

So for the Zork theme, do the following:

```
export BASH_IT_THEME='Zork'
```

To install pip (a packet manager for python), do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Afterwards, install pygments via

```
sudo pip install Pygments
```

argcomplete needs to be installed via pip as well:

```
pip install argcomplete
```

Comment: Thank you.  I guess no where in the documentation does it state that I need Python installed first.  I guess that's assumed with pip.  Installing pygments and argcomplete worked well.  But getting the theme to apply did not.  Following your instructions as well as https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/wiki/Themes

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Honestly, it's borderline impossible to help you without detailed knowledge about what works (and what doesn't). Does install.sh succeed without any error messages? If so, I suggest trying BASH_PREVIEW=true reload. to check if you installed everything correctly.